# trying to install bcrypt into node project + node set up issues

Tags: node.js, npm, mean

I have seen some very similar questions but none that I have found seem to work. I am trying to npm install bcrypt but i keep getting the error below.

bycrypt is the command that I use to install bcrypt modules. I do have Xcode and installing node-gyp does not seem to make a difference

```
regan@the-Voyagur buddha-bar (feature/styles) $ npm install --save bcrypt
npm WARN package.json mongo@0.1.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json mongo@0.1.0 No README data
-
> bcrypt@0.8.0 install /Users/regan/lighthouse/buddha-bar/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-gyp rebuild

xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance

xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLILeo' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'.

gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:343:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.0.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/regan/lighthouse/buddha-bar/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.33
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! bcrypt@0.8.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@0.8.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "--save" "bcrypt"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/regan/lighthouse/buddha-bar
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! not ok code 0
regan@the-Voyagur buddha-bar (feature/styles) $ xcode-select --print-path
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Comment: node-gyp has known issues on OSX see issues such as https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/issues/489 alternatively for bcrypt you could use a pure JS implementation (for a reasonable iteration count the JS versions benchmark just fine) https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt-nodejs

Comment: I called sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
and then xcode-select --install.

Comment: I found the solution at node-gyp github page: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/blob/master/macOS_Catalina.md

Answer (score 54, accepted):

OP managed to fix this for themselves with:

`sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/`

but graciously accepted my answer anyway.

Original answer below:

There are two distinct problems here.  One is that your `node` is slightly out of date and your `npm` is substantially out of date.

You're using OSX, so there are a number of popular ways to manage different node versions.  Here's a guide on updating node https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#updating-node-on-osx

Then you'll want to update to the latest `npm`:

`npm install -g npm@latest`

Finally, it looks like although you have XCode installed, something is still awry.  You report that this command yields

`$ xcode-select --print-path
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

On my system, which is OSX/Yosemite and **can** build native addon modules, I see

`$ xcode-select --print-path
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

You may need to switch your xcode path to a different directory.  For starters, though, please update to the current `node` and `npm` tools and try the installation again; if it still fails, the least dangerous next thing to try is

`xcode-select --install`

If none of that fixes things, let me know and I'll try to help further.

Comment: Hey Sam thanks for the help I have updated node and npm to the latest versions and tried running xcode-select --install but no luck. i get this regan@the-Voyagur buddha-bar (feature/styles) $ xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates

Comment: actually what you suggested along with this line fixed it `sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/`

Comment: I did not have the xcode command line tools so running the command `xcode-select --install` resolved the issue

Answer (score 9):

I was having a similar issue but with a different package.

```sh
node-gyp rebuild
No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.
No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLILeo' found at '/'.
No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'.
gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
gyp ERR! configure error
```

Running `macOS Catalina 10.15.2`, I tried the following:

```sh
$ xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, 
use "Software Update" to install updates
```

Fixed it by doing the following:

```sh
$ [sudo] xcode-select --reset
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.

---

**EDIT**

If someone is still running into issues, there's a thread on `GitHub` that has other solutions worth trying:

- [github.com/schnerd/d3-scale-cluster/issues](https://github.com/schnerd/d3-scale-cluster/issues/7)

Comment: Had the same problem but --reset didn't help

Comment: @3lokh look at this thread here - https://github.com/schnerd/d3-scale-cluster/issues/7#issuecomment-571915974 - and see if you can try some other options

Answer (score 3):

I had a simliar problem. Solving it was simple in the end. 
Just had to run

```
xcode-select --install
```

to install the newest tools and then

```
sudo xcodebuild -license
```

to agree to the new License terms. Afterwards bcrypt got installed without any problems.

Answer (score 3):

If `sudo xcode-select --switch $(xcode-select -print-path)` does not work for you, try re-install xcode:

```
$ sudo rm -rf $(xcode-select -print-path)
$ xcode-select --install
```

See more: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/569

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this by just opening Xcode, going to Preferences -> Locations -> Command Line Tools, and choosing it from the drop-down (it was empty before).

[image]

Comment: Tried a lot of commands mentioned everywhere, and finally this works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Following these steps helped me to resolve this issue on MacOS

- `sudo rm -rf $(xcode-select -print-path)`
- `xcode-select --install`
- `/usr/sbin/pkgutil --packages | grep CL`
- `sudo npm install -g node-gyp`

Answer (score 0):

Install xcode from(I prefer) https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ or `xcode-select --install` on terminal.

Then follow in order.

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
sudo xcodebuild -license
/usr/sbin/pkgutil --packages | grep CL
sudo npm install -g node-gyp
```